# What is the difference between [[]] and $ in list indexing?

Tags: r

Can anyone explain why `list1` and `list2` below are not identical?

```
list1 <- list()
lev1 <- "level1"
lev2 <- "level2"
list1[[lev1]][[lev2]] <- 1
list1
$level1
level2 
     1 

list2 <- list()
list2$level1$level2 <- 1
list2
$level1
$level1$level2
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is occurring because you are assigning a length 1 vector to a NULL atomic vector.

From `help(Extract)` -

> When `$<-` is applied to a NULL `x`, it first coerces `x` to `list()`. This is what also happens with `[[<-` if the replacement value `value` is of length greater than one: if `value` has length 1 or 0, `x` is first coerced to a zero-length vector of the type of `value`.

Change the assignment to `... <- 1:2` (or something other than a length 0 or 1 vector) and you will get the same result in both code blocks.

```
list1 <- list()
lev1 <- "level1"
lev2 <- "level2"
list1[[lev1]][[lev2]] <- 1:2
list1
# $level1
# $level1$level2
# [1] 1 2

list2 <- list()
list2$level1$level2 <- 1:2
list2
# $level1
# $level1$level2
# [1] 1 2
```

A simpler example of this, as mentioned by @alexis_laz in the comments, is just to begin with a NULL atomic vector and look at what happens.

```
x <- NULL
## assign a length 1 vector --> atomic result
x[["lev1"]] <- 1
x
# lev1 
#    1 

y <- NULL
## assign a length > 1 vector --> list result
y[["lev1"]] <- 1:2
y
# $lev1
# [1] 1 2
```

The result from `$<-` is always a list so I have omitted it here.

Comment: In a similar simpler case of `a = NULL; a$lev1 = 1; a` compared to `b = NULL; b[["lev1"]] = 1; b` this might more clear. Since `"[[<-"` is used both for atomic and generic vectors, R cannot know what the `NULL` should become and asumes a simple scenario.